# How to add an element right after the article using jQuery?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery

I am working on a wordpress plugin written in jQuery. I want to add a `div` element right after the article ends. Right now, I am doing this in the following way:

```
$('div.entry-content').append('<div class="my-div"></div>');
```

Will this be universal for all wordpress blogs? Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is fine. But better do it like-

```
jQuery('div.entry-content').append('<div class="my-div"></div>');
```

Cause the `$` sign doesn't work some time with WordPress. Better if you wrap your `jQuery` code with this below code-

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    // Write your jQuery code here.
    // And here you can use $ or jQuery as your wish.

})( jQuery );
```

Now about `jQuery` method, you can also use [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) or [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) to add something after the article tag.